# Problem with a hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I put a hyperlink inside a datalist..

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">'<%# Eval("ThreadTitle") %>'</asp:HyperLink>

                <br />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
```

I want it to enable it to be pressed so that the datalist event will be triggered and transfer me to another page:

```
    protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("AnswerQuestion.aspx?x=" + DataList1.DataKeyField + "&question=" + DataList1.SelectedValue + "&time=" + DateTime.Now);
}
```

Unfortunately, the link seems to be disabled and I cant press on it to trigger the DataList Selected event..

How can I make the hyperlink active ?

Comment: How do i do it with html..do i write <a href="">'<%# Eval("ThreadTitle") %>'<>

Comment: What is currently going to the client? i.e. what does the final HTML currently look like?>

Comment: This what is represented inside a cell:   <a id="ContentPlaceHolder2_DataList1_HyperLink1_4">'222222222222222222222'</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger a selecteditemchaned event use a LinkButton instead of hyperlink.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="sjdj" runat="server" CommandName="Select">
        <%# Container.DataItem %></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

In the code behind have

```
  protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("~/jjtestjj.aspx?" + DataList1.DataKeyField);
        }
```

Comment: But link button ruins all the presentation..I would rather that it didn look like a button

Answer (score 0):

why arent you using the Hyperlink as a hyperlink?

You can set the `NavigationURL` and `Text` using the `OnItemDataBound` (or equivalent) event.

this code works with an `asp:Repeater`:

```
protected void Row_DataItem(object row, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        var item = (DataItemPOCO)args.Item.DataItem;
        var link = (HyperLink)args.Item.FindControl("HyperLink1");
        link.Text = item.LinkText;
        link.NavigateUrl = item.URL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Navigation URL...lol..not so fast..if i could simply set the navigation url..i wouldnt ask that question...

Comment: why not though? DataList has an OnItemDataBound event. Is there something else going on?